# Static Method accessing Static variable

Tags: java, static, static-methods

```
public class Practice {
    int x;
    static int y;

    void functionA() {
        int y = 0;
        System.out.println("inside non static method functionA()");
        x = 10;
        y = 30;
        System.out.println(x);//10
        System.out.println(y);//30
        functionZ();
        System.out.println(x);//10
        System.out.println(y);//30

    }

    static void functionZ() {
        System.out.println("inside static method functionZ()");
        System.out.println("y: " + y);//prints 0, thought it was supposed to be 30?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Practice s = new Practice();
        s.functionA();
    }


}
```

Can someone explain why upon execution, inside functionZ(), y is printed as 0 and not 30? Before z is invoked, in functionA we've already set the value to 30. And since there is supposed to only be one copy of a static variable across all instances of an object, shouldn't it be 30?

Comment: You have y declared as local variable and it shadows the static declaration.

Comment: You are defining a local variable named `y` inside the function `functionA`.  When you define `y` inside the function, you hide the global variable with the same name.  When `functionA` exits, its local variable `y` goes away.  Since it is that variable that you have set to `30`, that assignment "goes away" as well.  In short, `functionA` is never operating on the global `y` you define at the top of your class definition. Remove the line `int y = 0;` and you will see `30` printed.

Comment: More briefly, 'declaring' a variable causes an instance of that name to appear, independent other instances.  'int y' is a declaration of a (new) variable 'y'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `functionA` you defining a local variable y:

```
void functionA() {
    int y = 0;
    ...
```

While you are in that function all access to y will go into this variable, so you set it to 30. This did however not impact the static variable `y`, which still has the value 0 and it is accessed from the static method `functionZ`.

To emphasize you want to access the static variable y rather than the local variable y, use the qualified identifier `Practice.y`.

Comment: Oh shoot, I completely didn't notice that FunctionA declared a new variable, thought it was assigning 0 to the existing static y. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference in global variable and local variable.
Global variables have the scope in the entire class.
Where as local variable have the the limited scope only within the method or the block in which it is declared.

Here you have declared static int y; which is global variable and can be accessed by functionZ().

Whereas the variable int y=0; declared in functionA() is a local variable, can only be accessed within the functionA() method itself. Meaning other methods DO NOT even know that variable even exists.

Lets say you remove static int y; and in funtionZ() method you will get an error beacuse it doesnt find any variable y